# Rapidminer 6.0.008 not saving web crawl results

Tags: web-crawler, rapidminer

I'm just following tutorials exactly to learn how to use rapidminer and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. One tutorial I tried was this: http://auburnbigdata.blogspot.com/2013/04/web-crawling-with-rapidminer.html

I set up the crawl web processes and connected it to the results port. My parameters are as follows:

url: http://auburnbigdata.blogspot.com

crawling rules: store_with_matching_url    .+auburnblogspot.+

follow_link_with_matching_url    .+auburnblogspot.+

write pages into files: checked

add pages as attribute: checked

output_dir: C:\Users\Owen Capobianco\Desktop\Crawldata

extension: txt

max pages: (blank)

max depth: 2

domain: web

delay: 500

max threads: 1

user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

obey robot exclusion: checked

My Crawldata folder remains empty and there are no results. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid wrong as this is basically my first time using the software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any sites of the form www.auburnblogspot.com. Try changing the regular expressions to something like `.+auburnbigdata.+`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. The author of that blog seems to have not updated his tutorial when he changed his blog name...